# how to validate parameter value in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

example contrived for this question. what is the best way to validate values of parameters passed in ruby on rails. I want to make sure the value of property parameter is one of the allowed values ( auto , home, boat). also what is the best way to validate id is a valid numeric value.

```
Module Lib
 class Service
  include HTTParty 
  base_uri "https://www.quotescomare.com"

  class << self

    def QuoteSearch (property, id)
     begin 
       response = HTTParty.get(url/property/id)
       if response.successful?
         filter_json(response)
       else
         raise 'invalid response'
       end
     end
   end
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the allowed values, you can create a simple constant with the valid values, like this:

```
PERMITTED_PROPERTIES = %w(auto home boat).freeze
```

And then you can check if the property is one of them:

```
PERMITTED_PROPERTIES.include?(property)
```

About the check to see if the id is numeric, you can do this:

```
id.is_a? Numeric
```

Comment: thank you. if id is passed as a query string. do I have to convert it to a number first? is there any inbuilt sanitizing built in so that nothing harmful is passed?

Comment: This way you will have to convert it to a number to pass it as a parameter in the QuoteSearch method. You can do it with `.to_i`, just mind that it will convert `nil` to 0, I am not sure if this is a problem to you. You can also filter the valid parameters using Rails built int strong parameters: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: thanks. I looked at that too, but i didn't see how to check for data type of params and how we can sanitize values from a ajax request. let me know if you have any more thoughts on how to sanitize the values?

Comment: I found two gems that may help you with that: `https://github.com/alfa-jpn/params_sanitizer` and `https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize`. The first one is not being maintained, though.